# Is it possibile in OpenCL to wait for an event that has not been returned by clEnqueueNDRangeKernel yet?

Tags: opencl

Let's say there are two Command Queues and I want to synchronize them using events. It can be done like this:

```
cl_event event1;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue1, <..params..>, 0, NULL, &event1);
cl_event event2;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue2, <..params..>, 0, NULL, &event2);

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue1, <..params..>, 1, &event2, NULL);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue2, <..params..>, 1, &event1, NULL);
```

Is there a possibility to achive similar results but with a different order of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel calls? For example:

```
cl_event event1;
cl_event event2;

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue1, <..params..>, 0, NULL, &event1);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue1, <..params..>, 1, &event2, NULL); //it fails here because event2 does not exist

clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue2, <..params..>, 0, NULL, &event2);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue2, <..params..>, 1, &event1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possibile in OpenCL to wait for an event that has not been returned by clEnqueueNDRangeKernel yet?

Not really, but there's a different approach possible.

You could create a user event (`clCreateUserEvent`) and use the returned `userEvent` instead of `event2` argument in the enqueue call. Then, after enqueueing a kernel that creates `event2`, you add a callback (`clSetEventCallback`) on `event2`, and from that callback you call `clSetUserEventStatus(userEvent, CL_COMPLETE)`.

There are only two problems with this, 1) even if the most common OpenCL implementations weren't horrible WRT user events, you're introducing unnecessary userspace trips (= slowdown), 2) they are horrible WRT user events. By which i mean, the callback will be called... at some point. It's not unusual to see it called with 10-200ms delay after the event has actually finished.

You could get more useful answers if you said what is the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: what is WRT? What does it stand for?

Comment: @EladMaimoni "with regards to" or "with respect to"